# Unity 3d Access specific Text Element among multiple children

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing UI for a game and Im stuck at a point where I need to access specific text and assign a value for each of it.
Case: Different teams have different number of players and each player has different stats(like strength etc). I have 'n' game objects( n varies depending on the condition). Hence, directly public refering to game obejcts manually is not possible. A Panel has 3 child panels. each child panel has atleast 3 text elements. Each element needs to have a different value.

I have an array of gameobjects. Each gameobject in the array has different text elements. So what im trying is:

```
 cards[1].playerName.text="A" , (or cards[1].playerName.text=anotherArray[1] )
 cards[1].Strength.text="90";
 cards[2].playerName.text="B" , 
 cards[2].Strength.text="40"
```

and I want to retrieve them :

```
 if(MyTeam=="Team1")
        {
             int i = 0;
             while(i<25 && Cards[i]!=null)
             {
                 Cards[i].gameObject.GetComponentInChildren().text = Team1Roster[i].ToString();
                 Debug.Log(Cards[i].GetComponentInChildren());
                 i++;
             }
        }
```

In the above method, the topmost Text element is getting selected.
How do I select different text elements from each object.

I have also tried this way:

```
while(i<25 && Cards[i]!=null)
        {
            Cards[i].gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = Team1Roster[i].ToString();
            var li=Cards[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();
            foreach (Text text in li)
            {
                li.text = "";
            }
            i++;

        }
```

Comment: Unity doesn't let you add more than one text element(graphic component) per gameObject as far as I know.

Comment: why a `while` llop there? And what was wrong with your solution on top like `cards[i].playerName.text="A"; cards[i].Strength.text="90";` etc?

Comment: @derHugo I have 25 player profiles and each profile has 5 text fields. so manually assigning 25*5=125 text fields is not a good idea right? So. I made a player array which has 25 elements. I want to change player[i].strength.text. but its not working.

Comment: Than you should probably get into [Prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) ... than you'll have to asign `5` references and automatically have them all .... what does `but its not working` mean? Please add all relevant code ... e.g. what is `Cards`?

Comment: You could do getComponent*s*InChildren<Text> and work from name or whatever criteria you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I have 'n' game objects( n varies depending on the condition). Hence, directly public refering to game obejcts manually is not possible"

This is why prefabs exist.

Create a script called PlayerStats, and give it the fields you need (Stength, Speed, Endurance, etc).

Create an game object. Call it PlayerObj or something similar. Add the PlayerStats component to it. Add whatever bindings you need (if you need) for the script, but all binds should be to objects under PlayerObj (or other components of PlayerObj itself)

For example, create a StrengthText as a **child object** under PlayerObj and bind it to PlayerStats.Strength

Make a prefab out PlayerObj.

When you create the objects you put in cards, those should be [instances created from the prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

Now each of those instances has the PlayerStats and **relative** bindings to their respective instances.

So you can do this:

```
     while(i<25 && Cards[i]!=null)
     {
         Cards[i].gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerStats>().Strength.text = Team1Roster[i];
         i++;
     }
```